# Get error with NSLayoutConstraint when I set them to certain size

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have 4 `UIButtons` with `constraints` on all 4 sides of each, and a width `constraint`. (`Xcode` made me set the width `constraint` on 3 of them, but I did 4, just to make things simpler in the coding.)

I then added all 4 width `constraints` to an `NSArray`. When I set the width `constraint` to the following:

```
[self.constraintArray[0] setConstant:cellWdith / 3];
[self.constraintArray[1] setConstant:cellWdith / 3];
[self.constraintArray[3] setConstant:cellWdith / 3];
[self.constraintArray[2] setConstant:0];
```

I don't get any errors. But when I set the `constraints` to this:

```
[self.constraintArray[1] setConstant:cellWidth / 6];
[self.constraintArray[2] setConstant:cellWidth / 6];
[self.constraintArray[3] setConstant:cellWidth / 3];
[self.constraintArray[0] setConstant:cellWidth / 3];
```

`Xcode` gives me an error saying it can't satisfy all the `constraints`. But in the simulator, everything looks as it should.

Error from simulator `Xcode`:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd51552710 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd514f64b0'Income'(62)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5155b630 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5155b410'All'(125)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5155daf0 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5155d8b0'Expense'(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5155de40 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5156e5e0'Button'(125)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5156eb30 H:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcd5156e5e0'Button']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcd515525f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5156ebd0 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5156e5e0'Button']-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcd514f64b0'Income']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5157f620 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd514f64b0'Income']-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcd5155d8b0'Expense']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5157f710 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5155b410'All']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcd515525f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5157f7b0 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5155d8b0'Expense']-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fcd5155b410'All']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd515bb460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcd515525f0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcd5155de40 H:[UIButton:0x7fcd5156e5e0'Button'(125)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

What can I do to not get the error?

**Update:**

Here is an image of the `constraints`:

[image]

Comment: on all four sides of what? SuperView? Clearly some of your constraints are in contradiction with each other in that second case... Quick sketch of your layout and constrains would be nice too... :)

Comment: Added image. all 4 sides of superView

Comment: All I can think of is that your fourth button is constrained to be some fixed size from right side of its superview, but you want him to be too wide. Hence contradiction. If this is true, xcode will break one of your constraint (which it does) and try to do layout stuff without one of the constraint. My suggestion would be that you try to recreate all your constraints in visual builder and see what happens... Hope it helps, good luck :)

Comment: THANKS!! I just removed the last constraint and it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log shows that you have 4 buttons, each with a fixed size. The buttons are each constrained to have zero gap between them and their nearest neighbouring button, (or the edge of the table view cell's content view for the ones on the edges). For all of these constraints to be satisfied, the width of the cell would have to be the sum of the constrained widths of the buttons. But this is not the case after only one of your constraints' constants has been changed: 125 + 0 + 62 + 125 != 375.

Since you are ensuring programmatically that your buttons' combined width fills the width of the cell, you can remove the constraint that ties your final button's trailing edge to the cell's trailing edge. That way there will never be a constraint conflict, even after just one constraint has been changed.

Also It seems that your variable cellWidth is an integer rather than a CGFloat, so you are doing integer division, which always returns an integer. 375 / 6 = 62, but 375.0 / 6.0 = 62.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  Select all buttons and clear constraints and make it reset to suggested constraints for both (Any Width-Any Height and Regular Width-Regular height size class). It worked for me.